# How to get the ID of Toolbar's Navigation Button?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-navigation

I have an Activity which implements OnClickListener, and I am handling onClick event as below code:

```
void onClick(View v) {
    final int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.xxx:
        break;
    }
}
```

and now I have a Toolbar also, So I want to handle toolbar navigation button click event in this way too:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(this);
```

but I don't know the id of the toolbar navigation button. How can I get it?

Comment: You can handle Toolbar menu clicks inside the onOptionsItemSelected() method.

Comment: you can try to add on click method directly to toolbar also which can help you, and for your above situation for home button id is android.R.id.home

Comment: did you get an appropriate answer to this ? I am trying to achieve the same

Answer (score 2):

If the toolbar is being used as an ActionBar, the view id will be `android.R.id.home` and you would use `onOptionsItemSelected(...)` to know when it's pressed.

If it's not being used as an ActionBar, the view id is -1 which doesn't have a corresponding id resource defined.

Which means you must use `setNavigationOnClickListener()` but in either of the two approaches:

either:

```
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

or

```
private View.OnClickListener homeClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ...
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(...) {
    ...
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(homeClickListener);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you [`Toolbar.setNavigationIcon()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar#setNavigationIcon(int)), the button (hamburger icon) has **NO_ID**.

That is why [`View.getId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getId()) returns **`-1`** in the `onClickLister` as @Adolfok3 answered.

> public int getId ()
>
> Returns this view's identifier.
>
> Returns
>
> int   a positive integer used to identify the view or NO_ID if the view
> has no ID

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#NO_ID

> public static final int NO_ID
>
> Used to mark a View that has no ID.
>
> Constant Value: -1 (0xffffffff)

Answer (score 0):

Just print a log to get the id, like: `Log.w("ID: ", ""+v.getId());`
In my case was -1 value.

```
switch(id)
{
   case -1:
    break;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the code and its changes to make it useful to future readers?

Comment: is the toolbar navigation button id. Just print a log to get the id, like: Log.w("ID: ", ""+v.getId());